# How to handle different button onclick within a cardview and passing intents?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a cardview which is presenting the upcoming events with title, date, etc. and there are two imageviews that should function as buttons: if clicked on one it should go to the participation confirming activity, if on the other on the detail activity. Both of these should also pass informations using intents(name, date, user id, token). I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMjI7cLsyfw&lc=UgzLCR3tROMvUVG9iw14AaABAg.992cIqHfCEJ992eVr0_nDp), because this was the closest solution to my problem but it still does not work. Whatever I change these are the errors I get:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference (this is given when  I call the setButtons function), or if the onclick somehow works the intents don't get passed and i get a nullpointerexception. I made sure I have used the right ids and names.
Additional information: i am using Laravel, and retrofit.
**EventsActivity:**

```
public class EventsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "EventsActivity";
private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 1;
private static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs";
public static final String EVENT_DETAIL = "EVENT_DETAIL";
private Context mContext = EventsActivity.this;
private Event mEvent = new Event();
private String token, name;
private int id;
private EventAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Response> result;
private TextView noEvents;
private Button add, more;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

    //Get token and id from shared preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    token = settings.getString("token", "");
    id = settings.getInt("id", 0);
    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: id " + id + "token " + token);

    noEvents = findViewById(R.id.noEvents);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.event_recyclerview);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new EventAdapter(mContext, eventList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new EventAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAddClicked(int position) {
           addClick(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMoreClicked(int position) {
            moreClick(position);
        }
    });

    loadData();
    setButtons();
}

public void addClick(int position){
    final Event event = eventList.get(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(EventsActivity.this, EventInvitationActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("name", event.getName());
    i.putExtra("name", event.getDescription());
    i.putExtra("name", event.getDate());
    i.putExtra("name", event.getLocation());
    Log.i("hello", event.getName());
    startActivity(i);
}

public void moreClick(int position){
    final Event event = eventList.get(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(EventsActivity.this, EventDetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("name", event.getName());
    Log.i("hello", event.getName());
    startActivity(i);
}

void setButtons() {
     add = findViewById(R.id.add_icon);
     more = findViewById(R.id.more_icon);
    Log.d(TAG, "setButtons: called");
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: add onclicklistener");
            int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            addClick(position);
        }
    });
    more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            moreClick(position);
        }
    });
}

//Listing events
private void loadData(){
    ApiEvents service = RetrofitBuilder.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiEvents.class);
    Call<List<Event>> call = service.listEvents("Bearer" + token, id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Event>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Event>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Event>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: loadData called");
                eventList = response.body();
                adapter = new EventAdapter(mContext, eventList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new EventAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAddClicked(int position) {
                        addClick(position);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMoreClicked(int position) {
                        moreClick(position);
                    }
                });
            }
            else if(response.body() == null){
                noEvents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Event>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Response", "onFailure: " + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

}

EventAdapter

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Event> eventList;
private static final String TAG = "EventDetailActivity";
private OnItemClickListener clickListener;

public EventAdapter(Context mContext, List<Event> eventList){
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.eventList = eventList;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onAddClicked(int position);
    void onMoreClicked(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_layout, parent, 
false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Event event = eventList.get(position);
    holder.itemView.setTag(event);
    holder.title.setText(eventList.get(position).getName());
    holder.description.setText(eventList.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.date.setText(eventList.get(position).getDate());
    holder.location.setText(eventList.get(position).getLocation());
    holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(clickListener != null){
                int position = (int)v.getTag();
                clickListener.onAddClicked(position);
                final Event event = (Event)v.getTag();
                if(event!= null){
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, EventInvitationActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("EVENT_DETAIL", event);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(clickListener != null){
                int position = (int)v.getTag();
                clickListener.onMoreClicked(position);
                final Event event = (Event)v.getTag();
                if(event!= null){
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, EventDetailActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("EVENT_DETAIL", event);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        }
    });


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title, description, date, location;
    Button add, more;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_description);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
        location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_location);
        add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_icon);

    }

}
```

And this is the way I am trying to get the passed intents in the two activities:

```
//Getting resources
    mName = findViewById(R.id.eventName);
    mDescription = findViewById(R.id.description);
    mLocation = findViewById(R.id.location);
    mDate = findViewById(R.id.date);

    mEvent = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getParcelable(EVENT_DETAIL);
   if(mEvent != null){
    mName.setText(mEvent.getName());
    mDescription.setText(mEvent.getDescription());
    mLocation.setText(mEvent.getLocation());
    mDate.setText(mEvent.getDate());
   }
```

And here is a button example within the cardview:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/add_icon"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/event_description"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:transitionName="img"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
           />
```

So the question is, how can I make this work?

**EDIT**
I have figured out what the problem is: the add and more imageviews are on the event_layout as part of the CardView and not on activity_events, where the programme is looking for them. But then, I don't really know how to make the two buttons work, when they are placed on the CardView.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyViewHolder` constructor you aren't initialising `more` so that will be null therefore throwing your null reference exception

Comment: thank you, I totally missed that, but sadly it is still crashing

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the on click that crashes is the `more` button click listener, if yes then its because you don't initialize the button `more`:

```
public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
    description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_description);
    date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
    location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_location);
    add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_icon);

    //here you must initialize more also
    more = itemView.findViewById(.......);

}
```

**Now to pass the data and get them on the other activity, I would suggest you pass the individual data:**

```
holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(clickListener != null){
            int position = (int)v.getTag();
            clickListener.onAddClicked(position);
            final Event event = (Event)v.getTag();
            if(event!= null){
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, EventInvitationActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("name", event.getName());
                i.putExtra("date", event.getDate());
                i.putExtra("description", event.getDescription());
                i.putExtra("location", event.getLocation());
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
});


//do the same for more button
```

In the `EventInvitationActivity`:

```
...........

//get the data
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
String date = getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
String location = getIntent().getStringExtra("location");

//set the data
mName.setText(name);
mDescription.setText(description);
mLocation.setText(location);
mDate.setText(date);
.........
```

Comment: I missed that I didn't initialize the more button. However, I did, and it crashes when I click on the EventsActivity. Same thing, nullpointer exception is thrown within the setbuttons function at this line:  add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() so I am still trying to find the problem. Could there be a problem with this one?:  int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());